# Which protocol should I be using for encrypted streaming?

Tags: encryption, tcp, streaming, udp

I am streaming a file (a MP3) which starts playing on a client after 100KB has been received. I need perfect playback.

I have to fragment the file so it can be buffered on the client, so would it be best here to use UDP + some sort of custom reliable delivery protocol? (Assuming I keep the datagrams small ~1400bytes)

Or should I just use TCP? If TCP - what size should I fragment the file to for best performance - I assume it will be related to the size of a TCP packet?

I read somewhere that the/a reason to use TCP instead of UDP + reliability protocol is that TCP does some fancy stuff managing/sharing the bandwidth with other applications whereas UDP is greedy. Is this true? If so, if I did decide to use UDP, would it mean that if I am streaming to several clients at once I would have to include some fancy algorithms to share the bandwidth?

Answer (score 2):

> would it be best here to use UDP + some sort of custom reliable delivery protocol?

Don't try to reinvent TCP. It's likely better than anything you could cook up yourself.

> Or should I just use TCP? If TCP - what size should I fragment the file to for best performance - I assume it will be related to the size of a TCP packet?

There's no need to split the file up at all with TCP -- it's a stream-based protocol, after all. Just start sending it all down the connection, and you'll receive the MP3 data as it arrives.

Comment: If I encrypt the whole file, I need the whole file for decryption surely? I don't think it would be that difficult to create a reliable delivery protocol similar to the reliability bit of TCP either unless its far more complex than I'm thinking.

Comment: Typically no. Most encryption schemes work on a single small (≤1 KB) block at a time, or on a single byte at the time in the case of stream ciphers.

Comment: when considering cipher modes like CFB every block cipher can be turned into a steam cipher